# print grouping array keys in output

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code for grouping arrays key data by size:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($productInfo as $element) {
    $result[$element['size']][] = $element;
}
```

and generate this grouping array using my code:

```
Array
(
    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => test
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => another name
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => name 3
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => name 4
                )

        )

)
```

I can show `key` name using this code:

```
<?php foreach($products as $key => $product):?>
  <h5> <?= $key; ?> </h5>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

But, I need to show output in html like this:

```
<h5> 14 </h5>
<span> test </span>
<span> another name </span>

<h5> 6 </h5>
<span> name 3 </span>

<h5> 4 </h5>
<span> name 4 </span>
```

How do can i generate this?!

**EDIT:**

this is my `productInfo`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => test
            [size] => 14
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => another name
            [size] => 14
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => name 3
            [size] => 6
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => name 4
            [size] => 4

        )

)
```

Comment: Can you provide output of `$productInfo`?

Comment: @HarishST: please see my update.

Comment: Are you trying to print `size in h5` and `name in span` ?

Comment: I think, your output of `result` and `productInfo` conflicts.

Comment: @HarishST: u right edited. sure i need to grouping with size(show in ` h5` ) and show name under size in ` span`

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your output of `productInfo`. Please confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
<?php foreach ($productInfo as $key => $element): ?>

  <h5><?= $element['size'] ?></h5>
  
  <?php foreach ($element as $index => $value): ?>
    
    <span><?= $value->name ?></span>

  <?php endforeach ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

If your `$productInfo` is the following:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => test
            [size] => 14
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => another name
            [size] => 14
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => name 3
            [size] => 6
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => name 4
            [size] => 4

        )

)
```

Then you can loop through each object and print the required values like below:

```php
<?php foreach ($productInfo as $key => $element) : ?>

  <h5><?= $element->size ?></h5>
  <span><?= $element->name ?></span>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: first method is true. in second way i cant grouping by size.

Answer (score 1):

Probably an easier way with your original `$productInfo` array that you don't show, but this will do it with the current array.  Just extract all of the `name` values from the current `$product` and `implode` them:

```
<?php foreach($products as $key => $product): ?>
  <h5> <?= $key; ?> </h5>
  <span> <?= implode('</span><span>', array_column($product, 'name')); ?> </span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Requires PHP >= 7 for `array_column` to work on objects, or use this instead of `array_column`:

```
array_map(function($o) { return $o->name; }, $product)
```

Comment: please see my update. u have better and easier way?

Comment: Actually no, you would need to sort it and then loop and keep track of the size changes.  But you could just build the list of names with spans in your original loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need two cycles.
Assuming your array:

```
foreach ($result as $id => $items) {

    echo '<h5> ' . $id . ' </h5>';

    foreach ($items as $product) {
        echo '<span>' . $product['name'] . '</span>';
    }
}
```